# Create a key value table using apache ignite sqlline

Tags: caching, ignite, sqlline

I am trying to make a table using apache ignite 2.9.1 sqlline option. **It's value part should have collection of generic key value pairs**.  It is very important.

[I want to create following type table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0Xs2.png)

I want to know , can I do this using using apache ignite sqlline option ?
Please  help me to understand this.

Answer (score 2):

Tables always have specific types in Apache Ignite. Caches may be of `<Object, Object>` but tables (which are also backed by caches) have specific column types. All columns in PRIMARY KEY are considered key columns.

This [example](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-reference/ddl) sums it nicely:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Person (
  id int,
  city_id int,
  name varchar,
  age int,
  company varchar,
  PRIMARY KEY (id, city_id)
) WITH "template=partitioned,backups=1,affinity_key=city_id, key_type=PersonKey, value_type=MyPerson";
```

Comment: Can't i make cache from sqlline?